# React Array is not an array

Tags: reactjs, react-props

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResult from '../SearchResult/SearchResult';
import PlayList from '../PlayList/PlayList';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {searchResult: [{name: 'The Real Slim Shady', album: 'Marshal Matters LP', artist: 'Eminem', id: 1}, 
    {name: 'Shizzle', album: 'My Dizzle', artist: 'Snoop Dogg', id: 1}]
    }
  }

  render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar />
        <div className="App-playlist">
        <SearchResult searchResult={this.state.searchResult} />
        <PlayList />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

import React from 'react';
import './SearchResult.css';
import TrackList from '../TrackList/TrackList'

class SearchResult extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="SearchResults">
            <h2>Results</h2>
            <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResult} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SearchResult;

-------------------------------------------------------------------

import React from 'react';
import './TrackList.css';
import Track from '../Track/Track';

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="TrackList">
              {this.props.tracks.map(track => {
                  return <Track key={track.id} track={track} />
              })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TrackList;
```

So I'm passing the state to a child element and than I'm trying to render it as props and I'm getting an error.

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, album, artist, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I'm lost and there are couple similar problems on Google but I can't work it out. Pls Help.

Comment: Please add the part where you're rendering the prop.

Comment: Hi, Can you share the code of SearchResult component

Comment: I edited your code.. before I could see `export class App extends` and at the end `export default App`.. the first export is a error

Comment: The problem is in `<SearchResult/>` it is trying to display the whole searchResult object. You have to explicitly tell it each thing to display in a valid element. For example, `<div>{this.props.searchResult[0].name}</div>`

Comment: SearchResult renders TrackList that has a attribute tracks={this.props.searchResult}, TrackList render method meant to render each track. So between the div I've got {this.props.tracks.map(track => {return <Track track={track} />})}. Now the error I'm getting is that map can't read prop but when I'm using DevTool the props are there. I'm lost.